# FTDI D2XX Driver not working on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, usb, driver, ftdi

I had just downloaded the latest FTDI D2XX driver for android from the FTDI site to interface my ft232R chip with my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone without rooting. When i insert my ft232r chip via usb to my samsung galaxy s3 it seems to recognize it, but when i start my application which uses the FTDI D2XX driver to extract the VID & PID it doesn't seem to recognize any device connected to the phone.

I'm not able to understand what the problem is as i've even updated the mobile phone. Can anyone please suggest me a solution ?

Comment: So if you iterate all the devices on the bus there are none?  Sounds like what happens when I put a "3D sound card" into mine -- Android doesn't install any driver so you can't talk to it.  Even though what I want to do is talk to it with libusb!  More dumb questions -- have you connected with another USB device to be sure the OTG adaptor your using works fine?

Comment: yes if i iterate for the device, it return's me zero. I've connected a HID device to my phone via the OTG cable, which worked fine.

Comment: All the signs are that Android has not installed any driver for this device, so you cannot get access to the "File descriptor" for the device without root access.  At this point I think I can only suggest to get in contact with the people that made the driver to see if they expect it to work on a GS3.

Comment: Actually the driver is a soft driver where it uses the USB Host API available in the android to connect, which means it should work without root access. Yes, i'm planning to contact the samsung guys regarding this.

Comment: One other thought was how much current the device is drawing from the USB bus.  The phone may be protecting itself.  If you had a powered hub you could see if that makes any difference.

Comment: my device is drawing around 20mA.

Comment: That's not the problem then.  100mA is OK too much over that can be a problem.